# Characters from two different arrays match despite them being different

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have defined a function that should, when called and given two strings, check whether letters of the first string exist in the second one. This is my code :

```
int lettersOfAInB(char a[], char b[])
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; a[i] !='\0'; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; b[j] !='\0'; j++)
        {
            if(a[i] == b[j])
            {
                count = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(count == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() 
{
    char a[5] = "zc";
    char b[4] = "oabq";
    int is;

    is = lettersOfAInB(a, b);

    if(is)
        printf("Yes");

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This will always output "Yes", regardless of the strings I give as parameters. Could someone explain me why please? Thank you.

Comment: Well, for starters, your `b[4]` in `main()` is undersized by one character. You neglected to account for space for the terminating nullchar. `"oabq"` actually occupies a `char[5]`

Comment: @WhozCraig is right, the only problem I can see with your code is the size of your `b` array. Because you neglected the space for the terminating `\0` your inner loop keeps going after `'q'` and reads 'random' bits of memory as if they were part of your char array until it finds a byte that is set to 0. These 'random' bits are likely to contain a `'z'` and `'c'` before they have a 0 so those are being matched to `a`.

Comment: You want to count the number of ocurrences of chars in *a* that are in *b* too? Or to return 1 if all chars in *a* are elements of *b* or 0 otherwise? Or return 1 if any char in *a* is in *b*, 0 otherwise?

Comment: @WhozCraig that solved it, if you submit an answer I can accept it if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone explain me why please?

Undefined behavior (UB)

`for(int j = 0; b[j] !='\0'; j++)` attempts to access `char b[4]` beyond its 4 elements.  Result UB.  Anything may happen.

---

If code it to treat `char b[]` as a *string* (an array with a *null character*), allows the compiler to make the array size as needed

```
// char b[4] = "oabq";
char b[] = "oabq";  // now `b[]` has 5 ellements
```